# execute a bat script and get its PID in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, pid

I am executing a bat file (child) that runs as java.exe from within a main batch file.

I cannot use taskkill /im java.exe as it will kill all the other java processes too.
So I would like to know the process id of the child batch file just after I execute it so that i can kill only the child batch file.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic process call create "some.exe" | find "ProcessId"
```

Here I've tried to create a tool that wraps this above and returns more neat result:
http://pastebin.com/D5rjF5CK
and 
http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1495

Comment: Thanks! I was able to achieve the desired output by changing configuration in the java program. But your script may be helpful to others.